# Compass Blueprint mixins not compiling?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass, blueprint-css

I'm trying to get Blueprint (SCSS-Syntax) working with my Rails (3.1) project. 
To keep it simple at first I set up a plain HTML file (outside my rails project) with some basic blueprint syntax, after installing compass and creating the basic scss files with:

```
compass install blueprint .
```

It produces a sass directory with a screen.scss that contains:

```
@import blueprint
```

among other stuff, but the stylesheets/screen.css doesn't contain span-x instructions, as I was expecting after watching Compass: A Real Stylesheet Framework by Chris Eppstein (http://vimeo.com/4335944) and most importantly my HTML is looking dull as ever.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <link href="/stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span-24">
                <center>
                <h1 class="alt box">asdfhlakshf sdfgs dgf sdf sdfg fsd g</h1>
              </center>
            </div>

            <div class="pre">
                asdfhlakshf
            </div>

            <div class="span-4 success colborder">
                WOW
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

My screen.css looks like this (small excerpt):

```
    /* line 44, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_form.scss */
    form.bp input.text, form.bp input.title, form.bp input[type=email], form.bp input[type=text], form.bp input[type=password] {
      width: 300px;
    }
    /* line 46, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_form.scss */
    form.bp textarea {
      width: 390px;
      height: 250px;
    }
    /* line 39, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_scaffolding.scss */
    form.bp .box {
      padding: 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 1.5em;
      background: #e5ecf9;
    }
    /* line 42, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_scaffolding.scss */
    form.bp .border {
      padding-right: 4px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    /* line 45, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_scaffolding.scss */
    form.bp .colborder {
      padding-right: 24px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    /* line 47, ../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_scaffolding.scss */
    form.bp hr {
      background: #dddddd;
      color: #dddddd;
      clear: both;
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.1em;
      margin: 0 0 1.45em;
      border: none;
    }
```

Calling

```
compass compile
```

Just tells me everything stays unchanged. But it does something once I add

```
@import "blueprint/grid"
```

for example. Still no pretty html though.

The second I copy a precompiled screen.css (downloaded from the blueprint website) to the stylesheets folder everything works like a charm. It's the same inside of my rails project. I can use the precompiled css there without problems.

I guess I'm missing something basic here I need to do for the compass compiling magic to work, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Versions

- compass 0.11.5 (Antares)
- ruby 1.8.7 (outside of the rails project)
- ruby 1.9.2 (with the rails project)
- using rvm 1.6.21

Installed haml 3.1.2 and sass 3.1.4. Though I think that this should not be relevant since I used html and scss, right?

Maybe I should have included more of my screen.scss:

```
// This import applies a global reset to any page that imports this stylesheet.
@import "blueprint/reset";

// To configure blueprint, edit the partials/base.sass file.
@import "partials/base";
@import "blueprint/grid";

// Import all the default blueprint modules so that we can access their mixins.
@import "blueprint";

// Import the non-default scaffolding module.
@import "blueprint/scaffolding";

// To generate css equivalent to the blueprint css but with your
// configuration applied, uncomment:
// @include blueprint

// If you are doing a lot of stylesheet concatenation, it is suggested
// that you scope your blueprint styles, so that you can better control
// what pages use blueprint when stylesheets are concatenated together.
body.bp {
  @include blueprint-typography(true);
  @include blueprint-utilities;
  @include blueprint-debug;
  @include blueprint-interaction;
  // Remove the scaffolding when you're ready to start doing visual design.
  // Or leave it in if you're happy with how blueprint looks out-of-the-box
}

form.bp {
  @include blueprint-form;
  // You'll probably want to remove the scaffolding once you start styling your site.
  @include blueprint-scaffolding; }

// Page layout can be done using mixins applied to your semantic classes and IDs:
body.two-col {
  #container {
    @include container; }
  #header, #footer {
    @include column($blueprint-grid-columns); }
  #sidebar {
    // One third of the grid columns, rounding down. With 24 cols, this is 8.
    $sidebar-columns: floor($blueprint-grid-columns / 3);
    @include column($sidebar-columns); }
  #content {
    // Two thirds of the grid columns, rounding up.
    // With 24 cols, this is 16.
    $content-columns: ceil(2 * $blueprint-grid-columns / 3);
    // true means it's the last column in the row
    @include column($content-columns, true); } }
```

I also tried changing my ruby version and renaming the sass folder to scss. I'm running out of ideas here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. It was something basic. I didn't uncomment the "@include blueprint" line, because I thought @import blueprint should be enough and I go an error message, when I tried.
Turns out the error message was solved by adding a semicolon to the end of the line.

Maybe the smicolon should be added in the shipped screen.scss. I'll send an email to the author.

Comment: Thanks for following up your own question -- I was hitting the same problem. The documentation for compass is somewhat lacking in basic details such as this :(